# Web2py and Pusher

Tags: web2py, pusher

I am trying to use web2py with Pusher.
I can push any messages in public channels.

I would like to use 'private' and 'presence' channels

Here a portion of my client-side code :

```
var key='xxxxxxx'
var pusher = new Pusher(key, { authEndpoint: 'auth' });        
var channel = pusher.subscribe('presence-chat');
```

'auth' is a function in my 'default' controller.

When I analyse the request in the browser debugger, I have a 403 error
when calling 'auth'

If someone can answer I certainly give more details.

Regards

Comment: What does the `auth` function look like?

Comment: Hy Phil,

I have found the solution.
In fact the problem was due to a proxy whith prohibited response
from web2py !!!

Thank you very much for your attention,
i will keep you in touch when my app will be descent :-)

Regards